# Find the concentration of proton after adding a acid to NaOH

Tags: aqueous-solution, solutions, ph

I have this simple problem that I cannot figure out though, only the first part.

> 100 ml of 1.0 $\frac{mol}{L}$ $NaOH_(aq)$ contains ( a ) g of NaOH.
>   After mixing 100 ml of 1.0 $\frac{mol}{L}$ $H_2SO_4(aq)$ with the
>   first solution, the concentration of proton becomes ( b )
>   $\frac{mol}{L}$

I got that there are 4 g of NaOH in the solution, but I don't have clear ideas about what should I do to find the concentration of proton. Could you advise me?

The answer is 0.50 $\frac{mol}{L}$

Comment: Remember that both protons of the H2SO4 are available to react with the NaOH

Comment: When you say "The answer is 0.50 mol/L", how sure are you about that? 
 Because I think it's wrong.  The 0.50 mol/L answer seems to assume that the H2SO4 donates both protons, but that's not the case.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a1}$ and $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a2}$ of $\ce{H2SO4}$ is about $-3$ and $1.92$ ($K_\mathrm{a2} = 1.2 \times 10^{-3}$), respectively. To solve the second part of this question, at least $K_\mathrm{a2}$ should be given. Since mole ratio of $\ce{H2SO4}$ to $\ce{NaOH}$ is $1:1$, the acid-base reaction taken place in the mixture is:

$$\ce{NaOH(aq) + H2SO4(aq) -> NaHSO4(aq) + H2O (l)}$$

(a) You already have done part (a) but I'll show you how to do the unit conversion:
$$\text{amount of}~\ce {NaOH} = \frac{\pu{1.0 mol} \text{ of }\ce{NaOH}}{\pu{1.0 L} \text{ of solution}} \times \pu{0.100 L} \text{ of solution} \times \frac{\pu{40 g} \text{ of }  \ce {NaOH}}{\pu{1 mol} \text{ of } \ce {NaOH}}\\ = \pu{4.0 g }  \text{ of } \ce {NaOH}$$

(b) Assuming $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a2}$ is given, to calculate $\ce{H3O+}$ in solution, we must consider following situations. Since $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a1}$  of $\ce{H2SO4}$ is large, we can assume following ionization (complete dissociation):

$$\ce{H2SO4 (aq) + H2O -> HSO4- + H3O+ \tag1}$$

Since $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a2}$  of $\ce{H2SO4}$ is very small ($\ce{HSO4-}$ is a weak acid), we can assume following ionization:

$$\ce{HSO4- (aq) + H2O <=> SO4^2- + H3O+ \tag2}$$

Now similar to the calculation in part (a), you can find out amount of $\ce {OH-}$ in $\pu{mol}$ in the original base solution ($\pu {0.10 mol}$) and the amount of $\ce {H3O+}$ in $\pu{mol}$ in the original acid solution (also $\pu{0.10 mol}$), assuming second ionization do not take place (hypothetically, if second ionization did not initiate, it is safe to assume that each $\pu{mol}$ of $\ce{H2SO4}$ would give $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{H3O+}$ and $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{HSO4-}$). When original solutions are mixed, each $\ce{OH-}$ ion react with one $\ce{H3O+}$ ion to give one $\ce {H2O}$ molecule and one $\ce{HSO4-}$ molecule remain unreacted, according to the equation $(1)$. At the end, $\pu{0.10 mol}$ of $\ce{HSO4-}$ ions remain unreacted, since not enough $\ce {OH-}$ ions have been added. Nonetheless, total volume now is $\pu{200 mL}$. Therefore, the initial $[\ce{HSO4-}]$ is:

$$\text{Initial concentration of }\ce {HSO4-} = \frac{\pu{0.10 mol} \text{ of }\ce{HSO4-}}{\pu{0.200 L} \text{ of solution}} = \pu{0.50 molL-1}  \text{ of } \ce {HSO4-}$$

Now, we can visualize the second ionization according to the equation $(1)$ wuold take place:

$$
\begin{array}{lccc}
\ce{& HSO4-(aq) &+ & H2O &<=> &SO4^2-(aq) & + & H3O+(aq)} \\
\text{I} & 0.5 \times 0.20 && \text{a lot} && 0 && 0 \\
\text{C} & -\alpha && \text{a lot} &&  +\alpha && +\alpha \\
\text{E} & 0.5 \times 0.20 - \alpha && \text{a lot} &&  \alpha && \alpha \\
\end{array}
$$

By definition,

$$\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a2} = \frac{[\ce{SO4^2-}][\ce{H3O+}]}{[\ce{HSO4-}]} = \frac{\alpha \times \alpha}{0.5 \times 0.20 - \alpha} $$

I assume you may able to calculate the final $\ce {H3O+}$ concentration ($\alpha$) now.

Comment: So, if I understood, when solution are mixed, 0.10 mol of $OH^-$ react with 0.10 mol of $H_3O^+$ so that only 0.10 mol of protons is in excess. Therefore, since the solution now is 200 mL I have to do $\frac{0.10 mol}{0.200 L} = 0.50 \frac{mol}{L}$. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since nobody has pointed this out explicitly, I believe this solution is wrong because it assumes the H2SO4 will donate both protons.  But H2SO4 is only a strong acid with respect to the first proton.  To determine how many molecules donate the second proton, you have to use the second dissociation constant for H2SO4.  The funny thing is that the OP said "The answer is 0.50 mol/L" which I assume came from an instructor or an answer key, which means the instructor got it wrong as well.

Comment: @Bennett The answer is from an answer key. Probably the exercise assumed that H2SO4 donates both H+. Otherwise, it would be less as you pointed out.

Comment: @TheBarbarios thanks.  Yeah I figured that -- the point is that the assumption is wrong, and gives the wrong answer :)